# javascript error console says xml cannot be the whole program

Tags: php, html, mysql

The firebug points at the end of the code to '?>' and says XML cant be the whole program,
I searched enough about this error but all talk about js & ajax.But my code has only html and i can't find any error here..

```
<?php 

    $con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','*****');
    if (!$con)
            {
                    die("OOPS!Could not connect to server".mysql_error());
            }
    mysql_select_db('EVENTS',$con) or die('Could not connect'.mysql_error());
            echo "<table>"; 
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>"."Time"."</td>" ;
                    $i=0; $j=0;
                    while($i < 7)
                    { $today = mktime(0,0,0,date('d')+$i,date('m'),date('Y'));
                    echo "<td>".date('d/m/Y' , $today)."<br />".date('D',$today)." </td>";
                    $i++;
                    }
                    echo "</tr>";
                    while ($j < 10)
                    {       $i= 0 ; $time = 8+ $j;
                            echo "<tr>";
                            while ( $i < 7)
                            {
                            $today = mktime(0,0,0,date('d')+$i,date('m'),date('Y'));
                            $row1 = mysql_query ("SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM EVENTS WHERE TIME='$time' AND DATE='$today'") or die() ;
                            $row2 = mysql_query ("SELECT NAME FROM EVENTS WHERE TIME='$time' AND DATE='$today'") or die() ;
                            $result1 = mysql_result($row1,$con) or "---";
                            $result2 = mysql_result($row2,$con) or "-";
                            echo "<td>".$result1."BY".$result2."</td>" ;
                            $i++;
                            } echo"</tr>"; $j++;
                    }
            echo "</table>"; mysql_close($con);
     ?>
```

Here is the code sent to the browser as asked by Quentin,seemingly not different.

```
  <?php 

$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','*****');
if (!$con)
            {
                    die("OOPS!Could not connect to server".mysql_error());
            }
mysql_select_db('EVENTS',$con) or die('Could not connect'.mysql_error());
    echo "<table>"; 
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>"."Time"."</td>" ;
        $i=0; $j=0;
        while($i < 7)
        { $today = mktime(0,0,0,date('d')+i,date('m'),date('Y'));
        echo "<td>".date('d/m/Y' , $today)."<br />".date('D',$today)." </td>";
        i++;
        }
        echo "</tr>";
        while ($j < 10)
        {   $i= 0 ; $time = 8+ $j;
            echo "<tr>"
            while ( $i < 7)
            {
            $today = mktime(0,0,0,date('d')+i,date('m'),date('Y'));
            $row1 = mysql_query ("SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM EVENTS WHERE TIME='$time' AND DATE='$today'") or die() ;
            $row2 = mysql_query ("SELECT NAME FROM EVENTS WHERE TIME='$time' AND DATE='$today'") or die() ;
            $result1 = mysql_result($row1,$con) or "---";
            $result2 = mysql_result($row2,$con) or "-";
            echo "<td>".$result1."BY".$result2."</td>" ;
            i++;
            } echo"</tr>"; j++;
        }
    echo "</table>"; mysql_close($con);
      ?>
```

The .html page when opened in browser shows this:

"; echo ""; echo ""."Time"."" ; $i=0; $j=0; while($i < 7) { $today = mktime(0,0,0,date('d')+i,date('m'),date('Y')); echo "".date('d/m/Y' , $today)."
".date('D',$today)." "; i++; } echo ""; while ($j < 10) { $i= 0 ; $time = 8+ $j; echo "" while ( $i < 7) { $today = mktime(0,0,0,date('d')+i,date('m'),date('Y')); $row1 = mysql_query ("SELECT DESCRIPTION FROM EVENTS WHERE TIME='$time' AND DATE='$today'") or die() ; $row2 = mysql_query ("SELECT NAME FROM EVENTS WHERE TIME='$time' AND DATE='$today'") or die() ; $result1 = mysql_result($row1,$con) or "---"; $result2 = mysql_result($row2,$con) or "-"; echo "".$result1."BY".$result2."" ; i++; } echo""; j++; } echo ""; mysql_close($con); ?>

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Where is java here ? Are you sure it's not a javascript console ?

Comment: It's hard to say with just that but I wonder if the PHP isn't served raw instead of being interpreted server side.

Comment: it is a homework question and i need to use mysql.@DCoder

Comment: @SLaks I dont know. The firebug points to the end of code where php tag has been closed "?>" <-- here. And says "xml cant be the whole program"

Comment: Errors reported by Firebug are *client side* errors, the server side code is (likely) beside the point. Show us the **output** of the PHP as seen via View>Source.

Comment: @sum What DCoder means is that you should use mysqli_* or PDO functions to access mysql. They're more modern APIs that are still maintained.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson okay.But would changng to those help me to get rid of this error? It doesnt seem to be related with mysql.

Comment: @sum No, your error seems to be related to not having PHP installed or enabled on your web server.

Comment: @sum — PHP is a programming language. You write a program in it. You run that program. You get some output. Usually that program is run via a webserver and the output is sent to a web browser. If you go to the view menu and then pick "source", you can see what the server sent to the browser. Firebug cannot see the server side code, so the error must be with the code sent to the browser. You need to show us that code instead of the PHP program that generates it.

Comment: @sub — See dystroy's earlier comment: *It's hard to say with just that but I wonder if the PHP isn't served raw instead of being interpreted server side.* – You need to add support for PHP to your webserver and/or configure it to run that program through PHP before serving it.

Comment: @sub The php file also needs to have the ending `.php`, if it's called  for example `.html`, it won't work.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks for being patient.I am using lampp,it supports PHP,right? And I have 2 more pages written in PHP. They are working absolutely fine.

Comment: @sum — lampp has been renamed, I can't tell when, but if it was a while ago then there is a good chance you have an out of date version with security problems … but yes, it does support PHP. If it isn't working for this file, then something is different about this file which stops the configuration from matching it as something that should be run through the PHP interpretor.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson  This may have been the problem but I have also used html above this code. I have tu use php between html. I have saved the file as .html file.It contains some css code above this php code.

Comment: @sum HTML works just fine with a .php suffix, the other way is not true though. Try renaming it to end with `.php`

Comment: @Quentin Xampp for linux. I downloaded version 1.8.1 not before 2 weeks.Its not outdated Quentin.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Okay.I will get back after doing this.I hope this is the problem.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Absolutely right dear..Thanks alot.

Comment: @Quentin Please help..read the comment above.

Comment: @sum — Stop trying to use the old API and switch to one of the modern ones (as mentioned in the first comment in this thread). If you continue to have problems then [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) about it.

Comment: @Quentin will follow the advice.However now all fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are serving PHP to the client instead of running it through the PHP interpretor on the server.

You need to make sure that:

1. you are accessing the file through a server (and not accessing it from a local file)
2. the server has [PHP installed](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.php)
3. the file is recognised by the server as one that should be handled by PHP (this is usually done by giving it a `.php` file extension)